# Loaded existing Project into Visual Studio 2013, getting namespace errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 onto my computer.  I had Visual Studio 2010.  Now I am trying to load an existing VS2010 project into 2013.  When I got to build it, I get 4 namespace errors.  The errors say:

```
The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting these errors?  When I type `using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;` at the top of the page, Intellisense finds the package just fine.

Comment: a lot of times I remove and reinstall the assemblies.  See if that works.

Comment: "assemblies" meaning "references"?

Comment: yes. sorry about that

Comment: Many of these are now included as Nuget packages.